# Spanning Tree that Preserves the Number of Branch Vertices

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Suppose a undirected connected graph $G$, denote the number of vertices in $G$ as $n$, number of branch vertices (i.e., vertices with degree $\geq 3$) as $n_{\geq 3}$.

My question is: Is there always a spanning tree $T$ of $G$, such that the number of branch vertices in $T$ is still $\Theta(n_{\ge 3})$?

Here, $\Theta$ is the [Big-Theta notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) in computational complexity.

I tried several examples and think this conjecture is correct.

This question is related to the [minimum branch vertices spanning tree](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04937) and the [degree preserving spanning tree](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Egendron/Pubs/19.pdf). However, neither of which provide an answer to my question.

Comment: Interesting question! What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: I tried several examples, and believe this conclusion is correct. P.S. If you think this is an interesting question, please give it a star such that more people can help to solve it :) @MatthewLeingang

Comment: @MishaLavrov The question in the body is what I want to ask. Sorry about the misleading in the title. I have modified the title. Besides, what I want is that the spanning tree has **as much as** $O(n_{\geq 3})$ nodes with degree at least $3$.

Comment: You want to write $\Omega(n_{\ge 3})$ or $\Theta(n_{\ge 3})$ in that case: $O(n_{\ge 3})$ is specifically an uppr bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is the complete bipartite graph $K_{3,n}$.

Here, there are $3$ vertices of degree $n$, and $n$ vertices of degree $3$. However, in any spanning tree, at most one of the degree-$3$ vertices of the graph can be a branch vertex, or else a cycle is created. Therefore there is no spanning tree with more than $4$ branch vertices (three from the side with degree $n$, and one from the side with degree $3$).

We can generalize this example to one where $n_{\ge 3}$ and the maximum degree are not as close together. Take $k$ copies of $K_{3,n}$, and let $\{u_i, v_i, w_i\}$ be the degree-$n$ vertices of the $i^{\text{th}}$ copy. By adding edges $w_i u_{i+1}$ for $i=1, \dots, k-1$, we obtain a connected graph with maximum degree $n+1$ and with $n_{\ge 3} = k(n+3)$.

In any spanning tree, there are at most $4k$ branch vertices: from any copy of $K_{3,n}$, we can choose $u_i$, $v_i$, $w_i$, and at most one other vertex, or else we create a cycle. This is only a $\frac{4}{n+3}$ fraction of $n_{\ge 3}$.

---

Here is an interesting partial result.

**Theorem.** Every graph with $n_{\ge 3}$ vertices of degree at least $3$ and maximum degree $\Delta$ has a spanning tree with $\Omega(n_{\ge 3}/\Delta)$ branch vertices.

(Note that this is asymptotically matched by the second example above.)

**Proof.** Begin by iteratively deleting any edges for which this will keep the graph connected and keep the same value of $n_{\ge 3}$. After we've done this, the vertices of degree $3$ or more can be classified into $3$ types:

1. Vertices of degree exactly $3$.
2. Vertices of degree $4$ or more with at least $3$ incident bridges. (That is, edges whose removal disconnects the graph.)
3. Vertices of degree $4$ or more with at least $2$ adjacent vertices of degree exactly $3$.

(Every vertex of degree $4$ or more must be type 2 or type 3, or else it has at most $2$ incident bridges and at most $1$ edge to a vertex of degree exactly $3$, so at least one remaining edge out of the vertex could still be removed.)

Every type-3 vertex has at least $2$ adjacent type-1 vertices, and every type-1 vertex has at most $3$ adjacent type-3 vertices, so there are at most $1.5$ times as many type-3 vertices as type-1. So if we forget about type-3 vertices and only look at types 1 and 2, we still have at least $\frac25 n_{\ge 3}$ vertices to look at.

Among the type 1 vertices, greedily pick a subset $S$ such that no two vertices of $S$ are at distance $1$ or $2$. This constraint eliminates fewer than $3\Delta$ other possibilities every time we pick one, so at least a $\frac1{3\Delta}$ fraction of the type-1 vertices make it into $S$.

Now pick a spanning tree as follows: for every vertex in $S$, pick all its edges (which cannot yet create a cycle) and then complete the resulting forest to an arbitrary spanning tree. In the result, every vertex of $S$ is a branch vertex, and so is every type-2 vertex (because those must keep all their bridges). As a result, we get at least $\frac1{3\Delta} \cdot \frac25 n_{\ge 3}$ branch vertices, which is $\Omega(n_{\ge 3}/\Delta)$.

Comment: I believe here is a typo: '... and every type-1 vertex has at most 3 adjacent type-2 vertices, so there are at most 1.5 times ...' It should be 'every type-1 vertex has at most 3 adjacent **type-3** vertices', right?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction. (Well, both of those are true, but "at most 3 adjacent type-3 vertices" is the relevant claim.)

Comment: I notice in the counter-example, $\Omega(n_{\geq 3})=\Omega(\Delta)$. So, I have another interesting conjecture: for a connected undirected graph $G$, as long as $\Omega(n_{\geq 3})>\Omega(\Delta)$, $G$ has a spanning tree that has $\Omega(n_{\geq 3})$ branch nodes. It is a stronger version of your theorem. Intuitively, this conjecture may be true because $n_{\geq 3}-\Delta$ still has a rank of $\Omega(n_{\geq 3})$. Any idea/counter-example about this conjecture?

Comment: I've added a generalization of my counter-example that avoids this. (Also, $\Omega_{n\ge 3} = \Omega(\Delta)$ doesn't quite make sense to write; you mean probably just $\Delta = \Omega(n_{\ge 3})$.)